# invalid delegate initializer -- function does not match the delegate type

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to create a thread in visual c++, but i'm getting this error
`invalid delegate initializer -- function does not match the delegate type`
and this is being applied to where i pass my method into the thread.

````cpp
COM_Selector^ port;
    Thread^ t;

    public: void thread_method(Object^ data) {
        port->checkConnection(t);
    }

    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, thread_method));
        try {
            if (!t->IsAlive) {
                t->IsBackground = true;
                t->Start();
            }
            else {
                t->IsBackground = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            Console::WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making it a `ParameterizedThreadStart` instead as i had a parameter in my method that I was mentioning, so i changed that line of code to this --

```cpp
t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this, &MyForm::thread_method));
```